# Wait for everything to load before showing

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if this is a good way to make sure all the images etc are loaded before the #main div is displayed?

In the #main div I have to load 97 images, and sometimes it isn't fast enough so it shows squares before displaying the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').hide();
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#main').show();
    });
});
```

Can someone give me some good advice?

Comment: I would probably just have `#main` hidden by default in CSS, but other than that this seems reasonable.

Comment: The `$(window).load()` shouldn't be nested within the `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Why not? $(window).load() becomes after $(document).ready() so... ? please explain :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look in to lazy-loading and only load the viewport (visible portion without any scrolling) then (if/when) the user scrolls the other images display. Would also cut down on bandwidth consumption.

Otherwise, assuming you're following standard HTML and supplying a width/height for the images pre-load, I wouldn't put that much effort into "pausing the UI" until they've loaded--Your layout should remain in-tact throughout the duration of the load and 97 images (assuming thumbnails of some kind) shouldn't take too long by today's standards.

Follow-Up: Here is a [lazy-load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) for jQuery that [does what I'm talking about](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html). (Basically what Facebook does with its news feed)

Comment: Brad Christie, thanks for taking the time to give an answer.
Its not really the size of the 97 thumbnails/icons that give a delay from time to time.
The cause of my problem with displaying al the thumbnails/icons fluently is rahter mysql based. 
The images are not in the mysql, but to define which thumbnails/icon should be displayed in which <img> is defined bij some settings in a mysql database... so, 97 queries :-)
But I am already looking for a better system :-)

Comment: user, the MySQL queries should be executed by the time the page is surrendered, no? That is to say, the delay should be even before HTML is visible and/or rendering which makes hiding and displaying the content based on load delay irrelevant? (Unless i'm misunderstanding the question).

Comment: wel,
i do a while loop with php. while ($i < 97).
with each loop I query the db to get the name of the icon-image that equals with the current $i number (SELECT icon from db WHERE square_id='".$i."' LIMIT 1)  an I generate a div holding the image... 
(this is because the layout of the 97 icons can be managed by a CMS)

for the moment, i cant think of another way, but as i go on learning... maybe... :-)
Maybe generating an array holding the images...

Comment: @Nomistake: `SELECT icon FROM db WHERE square_id >= 0 AND square_id < 97 ORDER BY square_id`?

Comment: yeah something like that :-) a bit different, because not al the icons reside in the same folder etc... but i will try it out... later on :-)

Answer (score 1):

That will be fine. However, rather than using jQuery to initially hide the `<div id="main">` element, you could instead use a CSS property:

```
#main {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i think i will make the change you suggest, just to make it more clean!

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-load all the images behind a splash page then hide the splash page once they are all loaded. I currently do this for 73 images (18mb)

Check the answer in link below will show you how.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13982980/1406211 - Demo Included