# JS function to preload images before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need a javascript code which loads an image into browser cache. What is the usage? read this:

When the user logs into my site, she/he gets redirected to a page which is "Redirecting you to control panel" and a progress is displayed there too. Now, this "redirector" page has a background, since user experience this page and sees it only 3 seconds, many times, background image is missed and there remains no chance for it to be loaded, since from the page load till the page redirection there is only 3 seconds gap. Here is en example of my ajax login:

```
$.ajax({
// do ajax stuff
success : function(msg)
{
  if(msg==true)
{
   // I NEED A FUNCTION HERE TO LOAD THEM IMAGE INTO CACHE BEFORE THIS PAGE 
   // TO LOAD THE REDIRECTOR PAGE. USING THIS, I CAN ENSURE THE EXISTENCE OF THE
   // BG IMAGE WHEN THE USER SEES NEXT PAGE. THIS BG IMAGE IS INDEED NEXT PAGE'S BG
   window.locatio.href = 'process/redirection/to/user-panel';
}
}
});
```

Comment: If your image  can't load and be displayed in 3 seconds, your image is too large. Possibly use tiling to reduce it's size, perhaps use a CSS gradient instead, or rethink if it *really* needs to be there. If so, google 'javascript image preload'.

Comment: I would agree with veddermatic. If an ajax doesn't return in 3 seconds for a single image, either your server is terribly under-resourced, or your image is just too large. That being said, this seems to be an application structure problem more than anything. You want to redirect the user then immediately halt at a progress bar?

Comment: Yes it is a very common structure. The user gets redirected to a page which is redirecting it to another page. Is this not familiar to you?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I have checked that now an to some extent you are right, my picture is 167 KB, but preloading could not be avoid as a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function will work:

```
function preloadImage(url)
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "/test/example.jpg";
}
```

Also, [here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982789/cache-dynamic-images-from-array-before-page-loads-using-javascript) that discusses something similar, pre-loading images on a splash screen, but the implementation is far more complex.

On the subject, if you don't have to use JavaScript, another solution using CSS and XHTML that could probably work on the redirect page can be found [here](http://perishablepress.com/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/). Otherwise, the code at the top should work. Hope this helps, good luck.